# export specific columns/fields of list to Excell and not the whole list. How?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, excel, export

End users doing export of list to Excel by going to List and choosing Export to Excel. Well this works fine, but the user wants only some columns to be exported not all columns.

I've created "another view" with only these 5 columns selected and clicked on export to Excel, but it still exports all 20 fields (all fields from the list).

I don't know why it Exports all columns to Excel.

The strange thing is : When I put Filter on the view, this works fine...

!!!And the user is now exporting and deleting the 5 columns manually from Excell, which we should automate.!!!

I googled and I was not able to find a solution, please advise what I'm doing wrong.

The solution should be workable and this is repetitive "Export to Excell task for End-User" with these 5 columns.

**ps**: currently we are using SharePoint 2010 and next month we will move to SharePoint 2013.

**EDITED:**

How can I prevent the "path" and "item type" be exported.

Comment: The export to Excel feature will export only those fields which are added in current view

Comment: @Atish: yes, just seen again sorry. but why are the item type and path coming can I prevent these 2 columns to be exported?

Comment: Yea ..... So edit your question that how can you prevent those 2 columns? Anyway, I don't have any idea to do that. Please edit your question. Some body will help you then.